# Access the window height in curly braces AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to get the window height in curly braces like `{{}}` within the HTML of my AngularJS app.

However everything I try seems to return undefined.

```
{{window.innerHeight + 'px'}}
{{$window.innerHeight + 'px'}}
{{$(window).innerHeight + 'px'}}
```

I've tried a few other things but no luck. How can I get just the window innerHeight with curly braces in an AngularJS app?

Basically I have a modal that I am trying to set the modal-body max-height to be 75% of the Window height dynamically...as the modal-footer is being cut off the page on some window sizes because the body is too large.

```
<div class="modal-body" style="overflow: auto; max-height: {{(window.innerHeight*0.75) + 'px'}}">
```

Comment: this is never a good idea, but you could create a variable equals window in your controller. then you print your variable in the HTML. 
scope.myWindow = window; 
{{myWindow}}

Comment: Yeah I'm not the most experienced with CSS styling, I had a feeling there may be some complications to adjusting the height based on the window size that I'm not seeing. Still need to think of something better to dynamically adjust this modal-body when the content is too large. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way would be to watch the value `innerHeight` of `$window` and assign it to a variable from your controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ return $window.innerHeight;} , function(newVal, oldVal){
    $ctrl.windowHeight = newVal;
});
```

But it won't refresh until a digest is called, for it to be refreshed you need to bind an event on `resize` and call the digest:

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7su5wgc/)

You would then be able to do:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="overflow: auto;" ng-style="{$ctrl.windowHeight: wh + 'px'}">
```

Since you don't use the controller to bind your values but your scope, your code could look like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ return $window.innerHeight;} , function(newVal, oldVal){
    $scope.windowHeight = newVal;
});
```

and:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="overflow: auto;" ng-style="{windowHeight: wh + 'px'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it directly through HTML, you need to create inside your controller a variable let's name it "**wh**" like so 
`$scope.wh = window.innerHeight;`

and then access it by using directive ng-style from your html :

```
<div class="modal-body" style="overflow: auto;" ng-style="{maxHeight: wh + 'px'}">
```